# Sum of Previous Yr

Tags: sql

I have a simple query which does the below:

```
 SELECT
        B.WEEK_DT WEEK_DT,
        SUM(A.PROFIT) PROFIT
    FROM    
    CUSTOMERS A
    INNER JOIN WEEK_TABLE B
    ON A.WEEK_ID = B.WEEK_ID
```

Now, I want to extend this query to get Sum of profit for all of yr 2013. That means, the above data gives me value at weekly level and i also want a separate column which give me 2013_Profit, summing up all weeks of previous yr.

`week_dt` is in the format of `mm-dd-yyyy`

also, we have an offset in the week table, if that helps:

```
 - WK_OFFSET    WK_DT
   -13  February 22, 2014
   -12  March 1, 2014
   -11  March 8, 2014
   -10  March 15, 2014
   -9   March 22, 2014
   -8   March 29, 2014
   -7   April 5, 2014
   -6   April 12, 2014
   -5   April 19, 2014
   -4   April 26, 2014
   -3   May 3, 2014
   -2   May 10, 2014
   -1   May 17, 2014
```

Please let me know how i can get another column for each customer which gives a sum previous yr  profits.

Some thing like the below:

```
Customer       Curr_WK_Profit                 Prev_YR_Profit
AAA                 10                           520
BBB                 20                           1040
CCC                 30                           1560
```

Comment: What is the database? SQL Server / Oracle / other??

Comment: Your initial query has a `sum()` but no `group by`.  Did the query get cut off?

Comment: yah.. it did. i was just writing a sample